# it is possible to disable the "Copy Link URL" in the html5 video embed code?

Tags: html, video, embed

I have a small project of doing some html5 videos embed on a site.

I use a simple HTML video embed code

```
<video width="560" height="340" controls>
  <source src="path/to/myvideo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
<source src="path/to/myvideo.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

so my question is that possible to disable the copy URL when you right click on the video?

I know if they really want to get the video link there are ways to do so.

but just at least if I can do that one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch right-clicks via JavaScript and thus prevent the right-click menu.

As you correctly noted though, it’s only a hindrance rather than prevention. HTML5 video is about direct integration into the browser and thus can also be saved like images, for example.

Comment: because the problem that this is going to be use in Wordpress

so I though this might not be possible

but I see many of the html5 video embed without that copy URL option

but most of them need the css/js file so I think isn't going to work on wordpress